# ScrollView Background not homogeneous

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, background

**Goal: Background with the same opacity "#A4FFFFFF" in a ScrollView containing multiple LinearLayout**

When I run my app in a "normal size screen" (phone size) where the activity actually can be scrolled, the background is evenly opaque. While when I run the app in a "big size screen" (tablet size) where the activity does not scroll, the bottom 1/4 of the screen has the background not opaqued, while the top 3/4 is opaqued.

How can I make it evenly opaque?

Here is a visual of the problem:

> Tablet size

[image]

> Here is my XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/randomnumber">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#A4FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/OptionsHeader2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="8sp"
            android:text="MATH{PROOF}"
            android:background="#546BF7CD"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="serif"
            android:paddingBottom="30dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Instructions1"
            android:layout_width="207dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:text="Please choose one or more operators. Then press on one difficulty and the game will start!"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#000000"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Difficulty"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:textColor="#E9D34A06"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textAllCaps="true"/>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Difficulty1"
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="58dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:background="#546BF7CD"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:onClick="setDifficulty"
            android:requiresFadingEdge="horizontal|vertical"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:text="@string/Difficulty1"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Difficulty2"
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="58dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:background="#546BF7CD"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:onClick="setDifficulty"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:text="@string/Difficulty2"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Difficulty3"
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="58dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:background="#546BF7CD"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:onClick="setDifficulty"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:text="@string/Difficulty3"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="left">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Operators"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="#E9D34A06"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textAllCaps="true"/>


        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/Add"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"/>

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/Subtract"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Subtract"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"/>

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/Multiply"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Multiply"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"/>

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/Divide"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Divide"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"/>

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/Exponent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Exponent"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"/>

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/Square_Root"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Square_Root"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="right">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:text="Additional Features"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="#E9D34A06"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Switch
            android:id="@+id/Negative_Numbers"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Negative Numbers"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>


        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/Teach"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Teach_Mode"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>


        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/DoSim"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Simulate"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/Sound"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sound"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

  </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `LinearLayout` only takes as much space as it needs, since this is the view which causes your background to be opaque, it only affects the portion of the screen it takes.

You can try adding a new `View` to the back of the screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/randomnumber">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#A4FFFFFF" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/OptionsHeader2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="8sp"
            android:text="MATH{PROOF}"
            android:background="#546BF7CD"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="serif"
            android:paddingBottom="30dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Instructions1"
            android:layout_width="207dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:text="Please choose one or more operators. Then press on one difficulty and the game will start!"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#000000"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Difficulty"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:textColor="#E9D34A06"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textAllCaps="true"/>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Difficulty1"
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="58dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:background="#546BF7CD"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:onClick="setDifficulty"
            android:requiresFadingEdge="horizontal|vertical"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:text="@string/Difficulty1"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Difficulty2"
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="58dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:background="#546BF7CD"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:onClick="setDifficulty"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:text="@string/Difficulty2"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Difficulty3"
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="58dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:background="#546BF7CD"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:onClick="setDifficulty"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:text="@string/Difficulty3"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="left">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Operators"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="#E9D34A06"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textAllCaps="true"/>


        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/Add"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"/>

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/Subtract"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Subtract"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"/>

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/Multiply"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Multiply"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"/>

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/Divide"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Divide"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"/>

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/Exponent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Exponent"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"/>

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/Square_Root"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Square_Root"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="right">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:text="Additional Features"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="#E9D34A06"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Switch
            android:id="@+id/Negative_Numbers"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Negative Numbers"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>


        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/Teach"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Teach_Mode"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>


        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/DoSim"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Simulate"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/Sound"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sound"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

  </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: When I run the app with this XML it crashed the app unfortunately